# What does Frame.__init__ do?

Tags: python, tkinter, frame

in the following code, line 5, what does `Frame.__init__` do? Could someone explain the concept behind it? Thanks a lot!

```
from Tkinter import *
class AppUI(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, relief=SUNKEN, bd=2)
        [...]
```

Edit:
[Full Code with correct indention here](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-menubar.htm)

Comment: It's calling the `__init__` method of its base class `Frame`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The class `AppUI` is based on the class `Frame` from `Tkinter`. This means the `AppUI` class is a *type of* `Frame` but with some behaviors slightly different or customized. Which means that the methods of the `AppUI` class may need to (in fact, usually will need to) call code from the `Frame` class. That is, `AppUI` wants to do the same thing as the `Frame` class, *and also* something else. That's what's happening here: when you instantiate an `AppUI`, you want it to be initialized as a `Frame` first, and then perform the `AppUI`-specific initialization.

Here `AppUI` explicitly calls its parent class's [`__init__()`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) method.

You can also do this using the [`super()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) function—and usually you would; it's basically required in multiple-inheritance scenarios. But because Tkinter uses ["old-style classes"](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#newstyle), you have to do it the old way here.

Comment: Do i understand you correctly: AppUI inherits from Frame, so: 'AppUI(Frame)' initializes my AppUI instance as a Frame instance first, but does not run the Frame's '__init__()' method? I thought that was the idea of the '__init__()' method, that it is run as soon as the class is instantiated ...

Comment: No, `AppUI(Frame)` establishes that `AppUI` is based on `Frame`. It does not do any initialization. That's what the `__init__()` method is for, yes.

Comment: Then what does 'is based on' mean? Maybe that AppUI gets all the methods from Frame? Thanks a lot for your answers!!

Comment: It means that if you don't define an attribute or method on `AppUI`, the corresponding attribute or method of `Frame` will be used. For example, if you didn`t write an `__init__()` in `AppUI` then the `__init__()` from `Frame` would be used automatically.

Comment: The suggestion to use `super` is a good idea in general… but Tkinter uses old-style classes (it might use some new-style classes and some old-style in 2.6+, I can't remember… but that doesn't really help because it definitely doesn't document which are which), so you're stuck with the old style. Of course 3.x's `tkinter` doesn't have this problem.

Comment: I've edited the answer to explain why Tkinter code does things the explicit old-school way. But I'm not sure it's needed here, so feel free to revert it.

Comment: Oh, good point, I didn't even realize Tkinter uses old-style classes.