# Why is my tkinter button not displaying, have I installed everything in the module if not how can I install it?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
#snakes and ladder
from tkinter import * #pygame is the module that has collections of functions that is used to create a window import everything from tkinter
import time

class window(Frame): #Frame comes from tkinter is what you think as a window

    def __init__(self, master = None):#The master widget defines the settings upon initialisation
        Frame.__init__(self, master) #This is called the frame class that has been built in python
        self.master = master

    def __init__window(self):  #creation of the init window

        self.master.title("Reagan Kambayi") #It changes the title of the title of our widget

        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)#The pack function will pack this in our frame

        #placing the button
        stop = Button(self, master, message= "Stop")

        #intialising the button that will start the stopwatch
        stop.place(x=0, y=0)




screen = Tk() #It must be written with capitalised T because there will be an error and it holds the components of the tkinter module
screen.geometry("700x500")
app = window(screen) #The app variable is assigned to the window creation which has the tkinter module

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Bad caption and why are you adding so many commands?

Comment: have a look at this [how to](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm) maybe this can help you.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, here we go.

```
from tkinter import * #pygame is the module that has collections of functions that is used to create a window import everything from tkinter
```

Pygame has nothing to do with tkinter and you're not importing pygame here, you're importing tkinter.

```
class window(Frame): #Frame comes from tkinter is what you think as a window
```

No, it isn't. A `Frame` widget is just that, a frame inside a window. It doesn't draw a window in and of itself. The parameter `Frame` in your example isn't even a `Frame` widget at all, it's value is `Tk()` which is the function called to draw the first window in tkinter.

```
def __init__(self, master = None):#The master widget defines the settings upon initialisation
```

I'm actually at a loss for what you're attempting to do here. `master` should equal `Frame` which equals `screen` which equals `Tk()` but if I'm correct you're overriding that and telling it to equal `None`?

```
Frame.__init__(self, master) #This is called the frame class that has been built in python
```

I don't think you're doing what you think you're doing here. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18924569/4528269) explains it better than I could.

```
def __init__window(self):  #creation of the init window
```

If I'm reading your program correctly then `window.__init__window()` is never called, so none of this function ever actually happens.

```
self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)#The pack function will pack this in our frame
```

You're attempting to call `.pack()` on `self` which is calling `.pack()` on `Frame`. Typically we wouldn't assign a value to `self` in this way (although this is valid), [read this](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/07/the-self-variable-in-python-explained/) to find out what `self` should be used for.

```
#placing the button
stop = Button(self, master, message= "Stop")
```

This isn't *placing* the `Button` widget, this is assigning the `Button` widget to a variable. Also, `Button` widgets are declared as `Button(parent, *attributes)` and there is no `message` attribute built in. Meaning what you meant to call was `Button(self.master, text="Stop")`.

```
#intialising the button that will start the stopwatch
stop.place(x=0, y=0)
```

This is where you're placing the button, but the function that contains this is never called, so it never happens.

```
app = window(screen) #The app variable is assigned to the window creation which has the tkinter module
```

What you're actually doing here is calling the class `window`, all this does in your current program is call `window.__init__()`, which in itself does essentially nothing.

---

This is meant with no offence but I think you're lacking a very basic understanding of tkinter and possibly even Pythonic OOP.

I believe what you're trying to do in your program is the below:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Reagan Kambayi")
        self.stop = Button(self.root, text="Stop")
        self.stop.place(x=0, y=0)

root = Tk()
App(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Actually `self.pack` would work if the inherited frame's master was set to be a valid parent such as the Tk root, which might have been what they were going for.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I'd made it clear enough. In their example `self` isn't a tkinter widget. So calling `.pack()` on it, won't do anything.

Comment: It is, window inherits from Frame which is a tkinter widget, so `self.pack` is valid.